# Solving environment: failed

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, opencv3.0, environment, failed-installation

when i tried to install OpenCV3 it is showing this error and other libraries are installing...

```
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda install -c menpo opencv3
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

  - _ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf -> ipywidgets -> widgetsnbextension[version='>=1.2.3'] -> notebook[version='>=4.2.0'] -> nbconvert -> bleach
  - bleach
  - ipywidgets -> widgetsnbextension[version='>=1.2.3'] -> notebook[version='>=4.2.0'] -> nbconvert -> bleach
  - jupyterlab -> jupyterlab_server[version='>=0.2.0,<0.3.0'] -> notebook -> nbconvert -> bleach
  - jupyterlab_server -> notebook -> nbconvert -> bleach
  - nbconvert -> bleach
  - notebook -> nbconvert -> bleach
  - pip -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']
  - widgetsnbextension -> notebook[version='>=4.2.0'] -> nbconvert -> bleach
```

Comment: i am having ...Python 3.6.8

Comment: I have no experience installing OpenCV on Windows. However, you are trying to install it to conda's base environment and it looks like a few requirements are clashing. Have you tried creating a new environment with `conda create -n <env_name> python=3.7`, activate it with `conda activate <env_name>`, and than install OpenCV with `conda install -c menpo opencv3`?

Comment: ```(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda create -n Open_CV3 python=3.6.3 anaconda
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done``` My environment is crashing again and again, after  multiple attempts i worked it out... There is problem in my environment how to resolve it @orangeInk

Comment: Why are you trying to install from that `menpo` channel? It hasn't been updated in years. [The `conda-forge` channel](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/opencv/files) has all the latest versions of OpenCV 3 and 4, including support for Python 2.7, 3.6 and 3.7.  That should install fine in **base**, but really you should use `conda create -n Open_CV3 -c conda-forge opencv=3`.

Comment: Thanks man... it worked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a new conda enviroment and install opencv from there. It's very likely there is dependency clash in the default conda environment.

```
conda create -n opencv4
conda activate opencv4
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

At least this works on my end.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is channel priority is strict. Try setting the following which should solve the issue:

```
conda config --set channel_priority flexible
```